# NUnit Is.EqualTo treats different refenceres as equal

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm copying an array like this:

```
var arrayOfMyTypes = new IMyType[1, 2]; //IMyType is an interface
arrayOfMyTypes[0, 0] = new MyType(); // that MyType implements
arrayOfMyTypes[0, 1] = new MyType();

var xRange = arrayOfMyTypes.GetLength(0);
var yRange = arrayOfMyTypes.GetLength(1);

var copy = new IMyType[xRange, yRange];
for (var xIdx = 0; xIdx < xRange; xIdx++)
{
    for (var yIdx = 0; yIdx < yRange; yIdx++)
    {
        copy[xIdx, yIdx] = arrayOfMyTypes[xIdx, yIdx];
    }
}

Assert.That(copy, Is.EqualTo(arrayOfMyTypes)); // true
Assert.That(copy, Is.Not.EqualTo(arrayOfMyTypes)); // false
```

To be clear, I want the elements be the same and the array a different one. So why are `arrayOfMyTypes` and `copy` considered equal by Nunit?

Comment: For completeness: if this test passes for different instances (references), then it means that your type overrides `Equals` in a way that returns `true` for the comparison

Comment: @Marc, or it does not override Equals, compares references of `MyType`, which are the same in this case (as intended) and so returns true

Comment: "for different instances (references)" - title states "different references"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to compare references rather than values, use [`Is.SameAs`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SameAsConstraint):

```
Assert.That(copy, Is.SameAs(arrayOfMyTypes)); // false
```